# Get Windows NT ID of user and use as a variable on Linux hosted Flask site

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask site where a user has to sign off a page with their id and I want to use their windows NT ID.  The Flask site is hosted on a linux server so using getpass.getuser() returns my linux username which is no good.  how can i get a users windows NT ID  and store that in a variable?  I've checked through but cannot see any possiblities.

Would I need to create a login page and store the id in a variable that way?

I've tried using javascript but doesn't work.  I've tried adding a drop down on the site itself for a user to set but it doesn't apply it or loses after the pages refreshes (plus that gives the user ability to sign off as other people which is not a possibility)

Comment: If your web application is running on a Linux server, where in this system is Windows NT used?

Comment: The users are using windows pc's and a chrome/ie browser to access the site

Comment: What do you want to have happen if a user comes to the site from a client that is *not* a Windows NT box? Is your Linux box joined to the same domain as the Windows clients?

Comment: It's for internal users only so they all have windows pc's.  They will be on the same domain as the Linux box

Comment: You didn't answer the most important part: is the Linux box *joined* to the Windows domain? (This will require using some form of interop, e.g. Samba, to have the Linux box communicate with a Windows domain controller for authentication.) An alternative that's worth considering is to build your own authentication/login form, and authenticate against the domain controller using e.g. LDAP. This is outside the realm of a coding problem, though: now you're into a system administration problem.